# an question about compact space

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem:**

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a  compact  space and $A$ a subset of $X$. Then $(X, \tau(A))$ is
a compact  space if and only if $‎‎‎\overline{A}‎‎ ‎\setminus ‎A‎$ is a $\tau$-closed subset of $X$ and $‎‎‎ ‎A‎$ is  a compact  subspace of $(X, \tau)$.

I can only prove one side of the theorem, but I do not know how to use closeness of $‎‎‎\overline{A}‎‎ ‎\setminus ‎A‎$ and compactness of $A$  to show $(X, \tau(A))$ is a compact  space. Can you help me?

If $(X, \tau)$  is a topological space, $A \subset X$,
and $A\not\in \tau$, then the topology with subbase $\tau \cup \{A \}$ is called the simple expansion of $\tau$ by $A$ and is denoted $\tau(A)$.

$\tau(A) =\{ U ‎‎\cup ( V ‎\cap‎ A): U , V \in \tau  ‎‎‎‎\}‎ $

Comment: What is the definition of $\tau(A)$ as a topology on $X$?

Comment: I added the definition of topology.

Answer (score 2):

The result is false. Let $X=[0,1]$, let $\tau$ be its usual topology, and let $A=\{0\}$. Then $\operatorname{cl}_\tau A\setminus A=\varnothing$, which is certainly $\tau$-closed, and $A$ is certainly $\tau$-compact. Let $U_0=\{0\}$, for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $U_n=(2^{-n},1]$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; then $\mathscr{U}$ is a $\tau(A)$-open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover.